# Why is this integral $0$?

Tags: integration, multivariable-calculus

I am trying to solve the integral
$$\iint_R y^2 dA$$
$R$ is a triangle with vertices $(0,0)$, $(0,2)$, $(2,0)$. This is a right angled triangle with sides $x=0$, $y=0$, and a hypotenuse $y=2-x$. I chose to integrate in order $dydx$:

$$
\iint_R y^2 dydx = \int^2_0 \int^{2-x}_0 y^2dydx  \\
\int^{2-x}_0 y^2dy = \left[ \frac{y^3}{3} \right]_0^{2-x} = \frac{(2-x)^3}{3} \\
\int_0^2 \frac{(2-x)^3}{3} dx = \left[ \frac{(2-x)^4}{12} \right]_0^2 = 0
$$

It would seem illogical for the volume to be 0, so I must be making a mistake somewhere. Is my approach correct?

Comment: The only way for the integral to be zero is by the domain having no measure where $y\ne0$, so clearly your result is not possible. But how do you find $0$ from the beforelast expression ??

Comment: It's not an area that you're computing! The reason that the integral can't be zero is that the function $f(x,y)=y^2$ is positive (except for the bottom edge of the triangle, which doesn't influence the value of the integral), so the integral must be positive.

Comment: Your last expresion isn't correct:
$\left[\left(2 - x\right)^{4} \over 12\right]_{0}^{2} = \left[\left(2 - 2\right)^{4} \over 12\right] - \left[\left(2 - 0\right)^{4} \over 12\right] = -\,{4 \over 3} \color{#f00}{< 0}$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have

$$\left[ \frac{(2-x)^4}{12} \right]_0^2 = 0-\frac {2^4}{12}.$$

Plus you have a sign error, the antiderivate of $(-x)^3$ is $-x^4/4$.

Comment: Oh right. I substituted $du$ as $1dx$, and not as $-1dx$. The derivative of $-x$ is indeed $-1$

Answer (score 2):

You missed something in the last integral, since:
$$\int_0^2 \frac{(2-x)^3}{3} \mathrm dx = -\frac{1}{3}\left[ \frac{(2-x)^4}{4} \right]_0^2 = 0 + \frac{16}{12} = \frac{4}{3}
$$

Answer (score 0):

Put the lower limit correctly and also one negative sign should come because of -x !

Comment: Which one of the lower limits is incorrect? With the $y$ integral, I start at $y=0$, and with the $x$ integral, I start at $x=0$

Comment: in the final expression did u put 0 ??

Comment: I did, because I am starting at a straight side whose equation is $x=0$. As said by E. Joseph, the problem was the failure of applying the lower limit

Comment: in the final expression if u put upper limit 2 it is giving 0 and if u put the lower limit 0 it will give the required value with an extra negative sign.

Comment: I derived $-x$ as $1$, not as $-1$, thus making the integral positive. I also forgot the lower limit.

Comment: Thats all what i wanted to mean !